# Задача на определение палиндромности

Tags: java

Решаю задачку на определение является ли введенное число палиндромом. И не могу понять, почему у меня не работает данный код. Метод `mirArray()` почему-то зеркалит как заданную ему переменную `mirArr`, так и переменную `array`. В результате они становятся одинаковыми и результат кода всегда `True`. Сам код:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Task {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println( "Введите число для проверки: " );
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int num = sc.nextInt();
    int [] array = convertInt2Array(num);
    int [] mirArr = mirArray(array);
    boolean result = Arrays.equals(array, mirArr);
    if (result == true) {
        System.out.println( num + " является палиндромом" );
    } else {
        System.out.println( num + " не является палиндромом");
    }

//        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
//        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(mirArr));

}
    public static int[] convertInt2Array(int num) {
    String temp = Integer.toString(num);
    int[] array = new int[temp.length()];
    for (int i = 0; i < temp.length(); i++) {
        array[i] = temp.charAt(i) - '0'; 
    }                                    
    return array;
}
    public static int[] mirArray(int[]array) {
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length / 2; i++) {
            int temp = array[i];
            array[i] = array[array.length - i - 1];
            array[array.length - i - 1] = temp;
        }
        return array;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ваши переменные `array` и `mirArr` ссылаются на один и тот же массив.

```
public static int[] mirArray(int[]array) {
  int[] result = new int[array.length]; 
  for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    result[length - i - 1] = array[i];
  }
  return result;
}
```